# Where is my sfml texture going out of scope at?

Tags: c++, sfml, square

So I have the infamous white square issue (again) and this time I'm returning references wherever possible, but to no avail. I have a `Level` that holds a vector of `GamePieces`, and each `GamePiece` object holds an `sf::sprite`. Here's the code trying to draw a sprite from `GamePiece`:

Engine.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"
#include "ImageManager.h"
#include "Level.h"
#include "GamePiece.h"

class Engine{
public:
    Engine();
    ~Engine();

    void Go();
private:
    void ProcessInput();
    void UpdateCPU();
    void Render();

    sf::RenderWindow window;

    ImageManager imgr;
    Level level;
};
```

Engine's function that does the drawing:

```
void Engine::Render(){
    window.clear();
    //draw wall tiles
    for(int i = 0; i < 160; i++){
        if(i < 60){
            level.GetWallTile().setPosition(0, i * 10);
            window.draw(level.GetWallTile());
        }
        if(i >= 60 && i < 100){
            level.GetWallTile().setPosition((i - 60) * 10, 590);
            window.draw(level.GetWallTile());
        }
        if(i >= 100){
            level.GetWallTile().setPosition(390, (i - 100) * 10);
            window.draw(level.GetWallTile());
        }
    }

    //draw BG tiles
    for(int i = 1; i < 39; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 59; j++){
            level.GetBGTile().setPosition(i * 10, j * 10);
            window.draw(level.GetBGTile());
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < level.GetGamePieces().size(); i++){
        window.draw(level.GetGamePieces()[i].GetPieceSprite());
    }

    window.display();
}
```

Keep in mind that the `wallTile`'s and `bgTile`'s are drawing just fine, it's that last for loop that's giving me white squares.

Here are the relevant functions and classes:

```
//level.h
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"
#include "ImageManager.h"
#include "GamePiece.h"

class Level{
public:
    Level(ImageManager &im);
    ~Level();

    sf::Sprite &GetWallTile();
    sf::Sprite &GetBGTile();

    void AddPiece();
    std::vector<GamePiece> &GetGamePieces();
private:
    ImageManager &imgr;
    //not sure if vector needed, or one sprite
    //std::vector<sf::Sprite> wallTiles_;
    sf::Sprite wallTile;
    //std::vector<sf::Sprite> bgTiles_;
    sf::Sprite bgTile;
    std::vector<GamePiece> gamePieces_;
};
//Level.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Level.h"

Level::Level(ImageManager &im) : imgr(im){
    im.AddResourceDirectory("images/");
    wallTile.setTexture(im.GetImage("walltile1.png"));
    bgTile.setTexture(im.GetImage("bgtile1.png"));
    AddPiece();
}

Level::~Level(){

}

void Level::AddPiece(){
    GamePiece piece(imgr);
    gamePieces_.push_back(piece);
}

std::vector<GamePiece> &Level::GetGamePieces(){
    return gamePieces_;
}

//GamPiece.h
class GamePiece{
public:
    GamePiece(ImageManager &im);
    ~GamePiece();

    void SetShape();
    sf::Sprite &GetPieceSprite();
private:
    ImageManager &imgr;
    sf::Sprite pieceShape;
};
//and GamePiece.cpp

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "GamePiece.h"

GamePiece::GamePiece(ImageManager &im) : imgr(im){
    SetShape(); 
}

GamePiece::~GamePiece(){

}

void GamePiece::SetShape(){
    //int temp = rand() % 7;
    int temp = 0;
    switch(temp){
    case 0:
        pieceShape.setTexture(imgr.GetImage("line.png"));
    case 1:
        pieceShape.setTexture(imgr.GetImage("llblock.png"));
    case 2:
        pieceShape.setTexture(imgr.GetImage("rlblock.png"));
    case 3:
        pieceShape.setTexture(imgr.GetImage("square.png"));
    case 4:
        pieceShape.setTexture(imgr.GetImage("lsquiggly.png"));
    case 5:
        pieceShape.setTexture(imgr.GetImage("rsquiggly.png"));
    case 6:
        pieceShape.setTexture(imgr.GetImage("tblock.png"));
    }
}

sf::Sprite &GamePiece::GetPieceSprite(){
    return pieceShape;
}
```

Lots of code, I know, but I really don't know where the texture is going out of scope, assuming that's what's wrong. Looking at similar posts, that's probably the issue, but again, I need help finding it.

Comment: In fact, too much code! Where are you instantiating your texture structure actually? Where is the class (`GamePiece`?) instantiating the texture as a member is instantiated and goes out of scope?

Comment: GamePiece calls SetShape() from its constructor, and this funcion sets the texture of the sprite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void Level::AddPiece() {
    GamePiece piece(imgr);
    gamePieces_.push_back(piece);
    piece.SetShape();
}
```

`piece` is being *copied* into the vector. The element that resides in the vector is not associated with the object that it was copied from (the one that is bound to the scope of `AddPiece()`). Therefore any actions taken on `piece` do not affect the element that was inserted.

If you need to access the element that previously `push_back()`'ed, then use `back()` to return a reference to it:

```
gamePieces_.back().SetShape();
```

You could have also just called `SetShape()` before inserting it into the vector.

Comment: I edited the code accordingly; I caught that as soon as I posted. Turns out, what I had before (What you quoted) didn't even render a white square. Now that I'm calling `SetShape()` before pushing back the piece, we're back to the white square.

Comment: @jburn7 You're also not putting `break;`'s after the last statement of each `case`. Maybe that'll help.

Comment: @jburn7 Also, make sure you do `window.clear()` before `window.display()`.

Comment: What about using `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<GamePiece>>`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Do you think the `sf::Sprite` in the `GamePiece`'s are being copied is the problem?

Comment: @0x499602D2 I rather think, there's need for a smart pointer instead of a copy for `sf::sprite`, when looking closer. Though the question is pretty unclear, and the code seems to be essentially flawed, at many points.

Comment: @0x499602D2 You are a genius. So basically, the case wasn't breaking, so the Sprite always took the last case's texture, which I don't have loaded for debug purposes. Add breaks, and viola.